# What issues should I watch for when rolling out CentOS as a desktop environment?

Tags: centos, deployment

I have been managing Debian, and now Ubuntu, desktop systems for a small shop for several years now. I am very comfortable with apt for package management and distribution upgrades. The Ubuntu installer has worked for every system I have needed to add. I have not touched Red Hat for many years and have never really managed any RHEL systems.

I have an opportunity to take over a RHEL and CentOS shop. I am looking for a list of issues / management concerns specific to rolling out RHEL and CentOS as desktop environments for multiple users who have a mix of Dell desktop and laptop systems.

What issues should I watch for when rolling out CentOS as a desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *yum* is the new *apt*, at least when it comes to using RPMs instead of DEBs.  The intent of the tool is the same, but the functionality is slightly different (for instance, Debian/Ubuntu uses a separate CLI tool to query packages for contents, while yum is more of an "all in one" approach).

Coming from Debian/Ubuntu, I can easily say that you will miss the "completeness" of the available packages for download.  There are several odds'n'ends that are handy to have but are *not* stock in a CentOS/RHEL environment.  You can easily add extra *repositories* (the equivalent of a Debian/Ubuntu apt site) to yum, but keep in mind that you're trusting the source you're adding, before doing so.  Nothing is more irritating than to find that [you need tool X to do task Y](http://www.vergenet.net/linux/perdition/), but tool X does not have an RPM available in the official repos (or worse: it [depends on secondary package Z that has no RPM](http://www.vergenet.net/linux/vanessa/)).  Bummer.

At some point, you will be tempted to

- pull in an RPM that is not a part of your distro, or
- pull in some other package format that is not in RPM format

While this (usually) works, try to avoid it.  RPM installs try hard to be distro-neutral, but I have seen malformed packages that made assumptions about certain directories being "there", where "there" is a directory path on some *other* distro.  Generally speaking, you're better off just downloading the source RPMs and rebuilding the package; the resulting packages will be built for your environment and will not have some of the crazy pathing issues that you can occasionally see.

From your end-user's perspectives, a lot of the Ubuntu eye-candy will be gone; instead, you get a rather vanilla-looking Gnome setup, nothing wrong with that mind you, just a bit *staid*, that's all.  The OOB software tends to also follow this "conservative" approach to a desktop as well, although adding the repo (as mentioned above) will remedy that if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that adding a variety of `yum` repositories would be helpful. The "official" ones are very sparse in certain areas.

You should also look at setting-up your own `yum` repository so that you're syncing to that, and then installing locally, if at all possible.

The repos I have:

```
epel-testing.repo
epel.repo
google.repo
jpackage17.repo
kbsingh-CentOS-Extras.repo
kbsingh-CentOS-Misc.repo
other.repo
remi.repo
rpmforge.repo
```

sample contents:

```
> cat jpackage17.repo
# Be sure to enable the distro specific repository for your distro below:
# - jpackage-fc for Fedora Core
# - jpackage-rhel for Red Hat Enterprise Linux and derivatives

[jpackage-generic]
name=JPackage (free), generic
baseurl=ftp://jpackage.hmdc.harvard.edu/JPackage/1.7/generic/free
#mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=generic&type=free&release=1.7
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-rhel]
name=JPackage (free) for Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever
baseurl=http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/1.7/redhat-el-4.0/free
#mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=redhat-el-$releasever&type=free&release=1.7
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-generic-nonfree]
name=JPackage (non-free), generic
baseurl=http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/1.7/redhat-el-4.0/non-free
#mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage_generic_nonfree_1.7.txt
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1
```

Just Google "yum repository " for specific directions on importing the GPG keys :)