# Problem when installing package using RPM

Tags: linux, rhel5, rpm

I'm new to Linux, currently using RHEL 5.

I want to install some package on my Server but there is an error:

rpm: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Note: before this error occured, I have installed libstdc++2.10-2.96-0.83mdk.i586.rpm, which is the dependency of nxclient-3.4.0-5.i386.rpm

Any idear pls?

Sarith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @wzzrd.

Additionally you can perform the following steps in order to restore you system stability:

- add [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo to your /etc/yum.repos.d:

  > su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm'
- find which package provides libstdc++.so.6:

  > yum provides */libstdc++.so.6
- (re-)install this package
- remove the wrong rpm:

  > rpm -e --force libstdc++2.10-2.96-0.83mdk.i586.rpm

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install RPM's made for Mandriva on your RHEL box. Try and find packages that are specifically built for RHEL. Try rpmforge, the EPEL repository or the vendor website, and look for RPM's that have .el5 instead of mdk in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question asked about CentOS workstations, which I posted some example `.repo` file content to: [What issues should I watch for when rolling out CentOS as a desktop environment?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12071/what-issues-should-i-watch-for-when-rolling-out-centos-as-a-desktop-environment/68671#68671)